# Multiple installation in a single database

Tags: database

I would like to ask, can I install multiple wordpress in one single database? Will the new installation automatically get new table names that differentiate it with the existing ones? Or will it overwrite the existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiple installations can share a single database.

When you [edit the `wp-config.php` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) for each installation, you must give each install a unique [table prefix](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix).

The process is also explained in [Installing Multiple Blogs: Single Database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database) in Codex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install multiple WordPress instances into one database. You just need to change the database prefix for each install when installing.
In wp-config.php you need to change `$table_prefix = 'wp_';` to something else, like `$table_prefix = 'xy_';`

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible, just give different table prefix

Answer (score 0):

Multiple WordPress Installation into a single database is possible and it's not so difficult.

1. The first of all you must install WordPress manually.
2. During the installation in your `wp-config.php` phase, you need to change the prefix "wp_" in order to allow multiple installations.For example, the first can be "wpblog1_" and the next can one be "wpblog2_".

You can use different prefix and use them to create as many installations as you need.