# one admin for 2 wordpress websites

Tags: plugins, database

I was trying to find an answer since many days. Can It be done that =>
Can we have one admin panel for 2 different wordpress sites ?

2- Can we have 2 different wordpress websites that uses the single database ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
Check the following solutions

1) [Multiple installation in a single database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233599/multiple-installation-in-a-single-database)

2) [Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database)

3) [Multiple WP install with same users database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103195/multiple-wp-install-with-same-users-database)

Comment: I have a question that is not clear,
I have 2 wordpress websites and I want that If I post on one site ,it will also be inserted in my other website too.

So , I want to know whether I have to use multisite ????

My second question is I have 2 differenet domains for e.g. abc.com , xyz.com

I want to manage these both sites from a single wordpress admin panel

Comment: @Ravi Badoni In multisite you will have only 2 options... One is use sub-domain or directory structure, For e.g. your site is "`abc.com`" and you can either have sub-domain like this "`xy.abc.com`" or your can have directory instead of sub-domain like this "`abc/xy.com`". But complete different domain can't be use in multisite as per my current knowledge and also by default you can't publish a post for all sites under multisite network at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can have single database for mustiple wordpress installation. To achieve this you just need to change Table Prefix in `wp_config.php` file before installation of wordpress.

Open your `wp_config.php` search for this

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

Here "'wp_'" is the default prefix which is use to add with every wordpress table in database. Just change this (_wp) into any other prefix for your second wordprss installation. like..

```
$table_prefix  = 'wp_2_';
```

**Note** : These change must be done before installation of wordpress in single database.

As an alternate and better solution you can use multysite concept to have more than one website using single wordpress installation. See [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/) article to know about how to create multisite in wordpress.

Comment: okay. I will check these now.